# How to transform dpx format with data as yuv format with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to transform a picture of yuv format into dpx format. Its seems that the default data format of dpx is RGB, but I hope that I can get a picture of dpx format with its data part as yuv444 planar format. What is the correctc command  in ffmpeg on the issue mentioned above?

Thanks

Comment: FFmpeg's DPX encoder only handles luma-only YUV. With color, it has to be RGB.